# Hibernate SELECT DISTINCT behavior

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, distinct

I hope that this question is not duplicate, because in another case I use google badly (shame on me) :-)

So, I can't find exact and clear answer for my question: Is "SELECT DISTINCT ..." in hql applied before setFirstResult() and setMaxResults()? I want to be calm that I will not have problems with pagination in my app.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is SQL / database construct. You won't have any issues with pagination. But as my colleague says - if you use DISTINCT, you are doing it wrong ;). It can get slow on bigger tables and the same result can be usually achieved in a different way.

Comment: @PavelHoral, I tried to do this by another way... I have ElementCollection and  CollectionTable annotations on field (by default lazy fetch) and when I execute my query with IN clause on this collection I have duplicates in the result set..

Comment: You will have duplicates only if you are using JOIN. You won't get duplicates with subselect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the actual question, yes the distinct result set would be determined before the limit would be applied. The `setFirstResult()` and `setMaxResults()` methods essentially are equivalent to a `LIMIT` clause on the query.

If you use both you are requesting that the distinct result set be limited between the indexes given to your two method calls above.

### An example:

You have a result set with 100 records. There are 20 distinct records found for column X. You set up the following criteria:

```
Criteria critiera = getCurrentSession().createCritiera(Foo.class);
criteria.add(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("X")));
criteria.setFirstResult(0);
criteria.setMaxResults(10);
List<Foo> fooList = critiera.list();
```

`fooList` would contain 10 results, from the start of the distinct result set of 20 results.

If you changed the above to

```
criteria.setFirstResult(4);
criteria.setMaxResults(20);
```

`fooList` would contain 15 results omitting the first 5 results.

<sub>It could be ambiguous how the result set would be ordered, so you may not get the same 10 results every time.</sub>

Comment: If I use Projections.distinct, I must to set Property for every field that I need in the selected object?

Comment: Yes, I'm 90% sure you do

Answer (score 0):

SELECT DISTINCT

When the keyword DISTINCT is used after SELECT, it works as a shortcut replacement for a simple GROUP BY clause. The expressions in the SELECT list are used directly as the . The following examples of SELECT DISTINCT and SELECT with GROUP BY are equivalent. From [reference documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/dataaccess-chapt.html)

```
SELECT DISTINCT d, e + f FROM atable WHERE a + b = c
 SELECT d, e + f FROM atable WHERE a + b = c GROUP BY d, e + f`
```

Comment: If you are [quoting documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/guide.html#N12A7B), would be nice to provide the link as well (and format it as an actual quotation).